# Can 4e druids use machetes?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons, druid, proficiency

I don't even know if machetes are in d&d but since druids can use simple weapons would a druid be able to use a machete.

Comment: Do you mean 'use' as in 'wield effectively in combat', or do you mean 'use as a tool'?  If you're asking if a druid can use a machete to chop his way through a thick jungle, the answer is going to be different.

Comment: Use machetes how, for what? What makes you think they couldn't? Is this a question about whether machetes exist in the game, or whether there is something preventing a druid from using one, like other editions suggesting a druid can't wear metal armour?

Comment: Also, that "what makes you think they couldn't?" is a serious question - when people are confused about something, it's useful to know where they're coming from so that we can defuse their confusion.

Comment: @doppelgreener I think the "in combat" is pretty clear, since it's tagged with [proficiency] and talks about a druid's ability to use simple weapons. ("What makes you think they couldn't" is fair and enough reason to ask for clarification, though.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the stats for a sickle. It's a light slashing blade, adapted from an agricultural tool.

Comment: YES! I was wondering why it was taking so long for someone to say "yes of course just reskin *X* as a machete," instead of approaching a 4e question with an inappropriately simulation-based answer.

Answer (score 6):

Probably not. A machete could best be represented by the base statistics for either a short sword or a kukri. Both are hacking/ slashing weapons that rely on the weight of the blade to cut through a target rather than relying on the point to pierce.

The short sword is a *Military* light blade, which the druid is not proficient in without a feat.

The kukri is a *Superior* light blade, which the druid is not proficient in without a feat.

Comment: The kukri is probably the closest to a machete in D&D

Comment: The Scimitar is also not that far off (similar shape, only longer), and the Spring Sentinel has proficiency with it. Not that sentinels are a good idea, or that druids have weapon attack powers.

Comment: This is sort of vaguely implied in your answer, but you might want to note that any character can use any weapon type if they take a proficiency feat.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, you can use a machete.

However, machetes are not explicitly included on any DnD 4E weapons list, so if you want to use one you'll have to consult with the DM first (which might be you?). There are multiple ways that this could be approached:

### Reskin an Existing Weapon

This is easy, but could seem uninspiring.

In this approach, you actually use an existing weapon, like a sickle or short sword, but just call it a machete and pretend it's a machete. I think most people are completely comfortable with this and it's a common and accepted way to handle these issues, especially in this edition.

For example, someone suggested reskinning a sickle as a machete. In this case, the druid would have proficiency with the 'machete' because it is a simple weapon. Also, the druid could benefit from any feats, powers, or features that affect light blades - as the sickle is a light blade, and could even use the 'machete' off-hand - as the sickle can be used off-hand.

### Create a New Weapon

This takes more effort, but might be more interesting. Personal preferences will vary.

In this approach, a new weapon called 'machete' is created. A few things need to be decided.

First, what **weapon category** does the machete belong to:

*1. It's an improvised weapon.*

This would be pretty harsh, but defensible given a strict reading of the rules. If this is the ruling, the druid should use a different primary weapon.

*2. It's a simple weapon.*

This would be ideal for the druid, as druids are proficient with simple weapons without taking a feat.

*3. It's a military or superior weapon.*

Druids can still be proficient in military and superior weapons, but they must take a weapon proficiency feat. This feat will give them proficiency with a specific weapon, so one would pick 'machete' when taking the feat. It would not give proficiency with all weapons in the weapon category the machete belongs to, just in the machete itself.

Second, what **weapon group** does the machete belong to:

Weapon groups are things like 'light blades', 'axes', or 'bows'. This matters because feats, powers, and features can all reference the weapon group a character's weapon belongs to.

Third, what are the machete's **statistics** and **properties**:

By statistics I mean things like damage and weight. It would be easiest to pick an existing weapon and use those numbers, or slightly modify them.

By properties, we mean things like 'Light Thrown' or 'Off-Hand'. If another weapon was chosen as the model for the statistics, it would be completely reasonable to copy the properties as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say not as a weapon. However, a machete can be used as a tool, instead. It's generally assumed you have such a basic tool when traversing the wilderness. But masterwork tools are worthy of being put down on the character sheet. (Like most tools, it can be used as an improvised weapon.)

Comment: I actually found the Machete item itself on page 97 of Ultimate Equipment Compendium Volume 1 which said it was a simple weapon.

Comment: Is that a 4E book?